# Why does nested Row/Column extend past container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Still learning web dev so here is my question.  I am wondering why when using a container class at the very beginning of my layout, and when adding a row with two Col-md-6 columns, the content extends past the container.  The two columns with the forms inside extend past the jumbotron on both sides.  Just confused.  I think if I add an another container it would even it all out.  Just dont know why that would be needed.

```js
var toggle = function(){
 var exists = document.querySelector("#existButton");
 console.log(exists.innerHTML);


 if(exists.classList.contains("btn-warning")){
  exists.classList.remove("btn-warning");
  exists.classList.add("btn-info");
  exists.innerHTML = "copy";
  //document.getElementById("#existButton").innerHTML = 'check'
 } else {
  exists.classList.remove("btn-info");
  exists.classList.add("btn-warning");
  exists.innerHTML="check";
  //document.getElementById("#existButton").innerHTML = 'copy'
 }

 
 

}
```

```css
body{
 /*background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  to right,
  #050210,
  #050210 50px,
  #271f41 50px,
  #271f41 100px
 )*/

 background-image: url(images/body_background.png); 
 
}
.jumbotron {
 margin-bottom: 0;
 background-color: #cbd0d3;

}

.container .jumbotron{
 border-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar{
 margin-bottom: 0;
 background-color: #44abe2;
 margin-top: 30px;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
 color: white;

}

.navbar .navbar-default {
 border-radius: 0px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand{
 color: white;
}

.automatic {
 background-color: #6e8a99;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
 
}

.manual {
 background-color: #83929a;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

#ml-2{
  padding-right:0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


    <title>Mailbox Creator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Mailbox Management
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">User Mailbox Management</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Resource Mailbox Management</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mailbox Update Management</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link">Hello Username</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>


      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="text-center">Mailbox Creator Pro</h1>
      </div>



      <div class="row ">
        <!--  ***************************************** -->
        <!--  **********  Automatic Form  ************* -->
        <!--  ***************************************** -->
        <div class="col-md-6 automatic">
          <form>        
            <h4 class="text-center pb-2"><u>Automatic</u></h4>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" id="ml-2" for="accountName">Account Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input class="form-control form-control-sm " type="text" name="accountNameAuto" value="" placeholder="Account number">
                </div>  
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm ">Create</button>
                </div>
            </div>    
          </form>
          <form>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label"  id="ml-2" for="emailCheckAutomatic">Does account have email?</label>
              <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="emailCheckAutomatic" value="" placeholder="check for email account">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm mt-3">Check</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm mb-1" ></textarea>
        </div>


        <!--  ***************************************** -->
        <!--  **********  Manual Form  **************** -->
        <!--  ***************************************** -->
        <div class="col-md-6 manual">
          <form>        
            <h4 class="text-center pb-2"><u>Manual</u></h4>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-1 col-form-label " for="accountName">Email</label>
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm " type="text" name="accountNameManual" value="" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
              <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label" for="accountName">Account</label>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="S#">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Create</button>
              </div>
            </div>        
          </form>      
          <form>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label class="col-md-1 col-form-label ml-1" for="emailCheckAutomatic">Email exist?</label>
              <div class="col-md-5 mt-3">
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="emailCheckAutomatic" value="" placeholder="check for email account">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 mt-3">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="existButton" onclick="toggle()">Check</a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-1 mt-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"  >Copy</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm mb-1" ></textarea>
        </div>

      </div><!-- End Row -->


    </div> <!--  End Container  -->



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap, left/right **padding** (15px) on the columns is used to create the gutter/spacing between columns (`col-*`). The `.row` counteracts the padding by using **negative margins** (-15px) so that the outer columns (first/last) in any row are aligned to the edge of the container (and other content on the page).

[image]

In your case, a `background-color` has been applied to `.automatic` and `.manual` which are columns. Because the bg color is on the columns (and not the *content* of the columns), it appears that the columns are overflowing the row (which they actually are as explained above for the gutter.)

So for side alignment with other items in the `container`, you should apply the `background-color` to the *content* of the columns instead...

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/s07FmLZKuY

```
.automatic {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}

.automatic > form {
    background-color: #6e8a99;
}

.manual {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

.manual > form {
    background-color: #6e8a99;
}
```

You may also want to add padding to the inner forms if you don't want their content against the edge.

---

More on the "gutter" in the Bootstrap docs..

> Each column has horizontal padding (called a gutter) for controlling
>   the space between them. This padding is then counteracted on the rows
>   with negative margins. This way, all the content in your columns is
>   visually aligned down the left side.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does nested Row/Column extend past container

That's because a Bootstrap `row` normally has gutters i.e. 15px margin on each side of each Bootstrap column that sits inside a Bootstrap row. So, that results in 15px margins on the outside and 30 px between the columns.

To remove the gutters, add the class `no-gutters` to the row.

To add some padding to the columns now, you can add a spacing class like `px-3` to the columns. `px-3` means "horizontal padding 3 units".